# Record video streaming from a server while viewed via Windows Media Player

Tags: video, download, streaming, recording

I'm watching video from one server via Windows Media Player, is it possible to record this video while I'm watching it?

I tried with download master but it doesn't work.

Comment: not exactly "recording"; you're really trying to download a video stream.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use mencoder to record your screen. Its free and very powerful. I haven't tried it on windows but it works like a charm on linux :).

Comment: Recording the screen usually only gets very few of the actual frames the screen displays, it would produce a video with tons of missing frames, and due to re-rendering probably bad graphics.  good try though.

Comment: Agree with Daisetsu

Answer (score 1):

It entirely depends on the presence of DRM, encoding, and if you possess the legal right to do so.
If you want an answer which will work for pretty much any file, you could use something like wireshark or tcpdump and reconstruct the stream, maybe form a file out of it.

There are some programs such as RealPlayer which allow you to record streams, but that's the only one I really know of.  Maybe VLC (FIle->Save As).