# Download videos from Delve Player

Tags: video, browser, download, flash

I am trying to download a video from this [website](http://www.daystar.com/ondemand/marcus-lamb-life-in-the-spirit-rhema-bible-church-1-10-2010/#.UPxqwoYwSKG).

I am using Firefox and I have tried using many types of downloaders, but they only get the player and other Shockwave components instead of the video.

Comment: Example of such video:
http://assets.delvenetworks.com/player/loader.swf?mediaId=611d2f750bb546fda515cdb4b9701b29

Comment: WARNING: ***StreamTransport*** installs **A LOT** of adware. I tried the suggested downloads above and got an adware attack because of StreamTransport.

Comment: I haven't gotten any adware from StreamTransport and it worked, but I was probably an exception. I haven't used it sense though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some ideas:

- if you have the stream URL, try [VLC Player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) (it supports HTTP, RTSP, RTMP, MMS (e.g. WMV, ASF), FTP, RTP/UDP, etc.), you can [output the stream](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/257045-How-to-record-streaming-WMV-ASF-MMS-links-using-VLC-Media-Player) to the file from GUI or command line
- try [Video DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) extension for Firefox
- try [Grab Any Media](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grab-any-media/hkcaohgalmoefengeadahaaagpkbggok) for Chrome browser,
- on Windows, try [RTMP Explorer](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/RTMPExplorer), should work well (in *nix you can run it under wine)
- download standalone [Adobe Player](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) and try there
- on Windows, try [StreamTransport](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/StreamTransport)
- on Linux/Mac, Firefox stores the video in /tmp/. In example one of the youtube video is stored as /tmp/FlashllvkDZ
  Just copy the file to a safe place before rebooting erases it. Also Firefox often erases it when you go to the next video.
- try [gnash](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/) or [ffplay](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/)

  e.g. `gnash http://example.com/loader.swf?mediaId=53bb595914544ff2ae0d45a499b5dd23`
- try mplayer (only if the link is a flash movie)

  e.g.: `mplayer -dumpstream -dumpfile test.swf "http://assets.espn.go.com/swf/espnradio/08/stations_stw1.swf?&callsign=WTEMAMAAC&mp3cs=WTEMAM"`
- try [RTMPDumpHelper](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/rtmp_dump_helper.html)
- you can use [RTMPDump](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/RTMPDump) to dump it, command example:
  `rtmpdump -r "rtmpe://mbc2.csl.delvenetworks.com:1935/a6344/d1/" -a "a6344/d1/" -f "WIN 11,1,102,55" -W "http://s.delvenetworks.com/deployments/player/player-3.37.5.12.swf" -p "http://shahid.mbc.net/media/video/25857/59" -y "mp4:media/2fda1d3fd7ab453cad983544e8ed70e4/97077312a6ac4572892a4bfdba75b9a3-098cac003c11481db1ae72e974a7244f/style_s2012_e59_vod.mp4" -o "style_s2012_e59_vod.flv"`

If you still can't figure it out, use [swfdec](http://swfdec.freedesktop.org/wiki/) or [swftools](http://www.swftools.org/) (SWFExtract) to dump/debug the data from flash file directly.
You can also debug the flash URL online with [Show My Code](http://www.showmycode.com/) and look for any direct links.

See more information at:

- [VideoLAN Streaming Howto](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/)
- [Thread: How to record streaming WMV/ASF/MMS-links using VLC Media Player](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/257045-How-to-record-streaming-WMV-ASF-MMS-links-using-VLC-Media-Player)
- [How to find the stream behind a Flash player](https://superuser.com/questions/114196/how-to-find-the-stream-behind-a-flash-player)
- [command line tool to play swf internet streams?](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/command-line-tool-to-play-swf-internet-streams-662002/)
- [How do you decompile a swf file?](https://superuser.com/questions/114196/how-to-find-the-stream-behind-a-flash-player)
- [solution for saving .flv files with 11.10 and firefox?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1933602)
- [How to use RTMPDump? - rtmp dump tutorials](http://stream-recorder.com/forum/use-rtmpdump-rtmp-dump-tutorials-t8911.html)
- [Revisiting rtmpdump](http://constcuriosity.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/revisiting-rtmpdump.html)
- [YouTube - How to Capture RTMP Stream - RTMPSuck](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1PtnSGNPlg)
- [How to run SWF without a browser (on a linux server)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838085/how-to-run-swf-without-a-browser-on-a-linux-server)
- [Thread: How to download Delve Player videos?](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/342884-How-to-download-Delve-Player-videos)
- [RTMPExplorer offers one feature that StreamTransport doesn't](http://pastebin.com/bZ2kaFSu)
- [Record video streaming from a server while viewed via Windows Media Player](https://superuser.com/questions/149445/record-video-streaming-from-a-server-while-viewed-via-windows-media-player)
- [Learning rtmpdump Through Examples](http://eu.blackpanther.hu/2012/01/learning-rtmpdump-through-examples/)
- [Thread: online TV ... using rtmpdump, rtmpsrv and rtmpsuck](http://murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?t=80021)
- [HOW TO download mms stream with mplayer](http://ubuntuhowtos.com/howtos/download_mms_stream)
- [How to Download from MMS, MMSH, RTSP Protocol in Ubuntu (Linux)](http://blog.mbirgin.com/?c=page&ID=587)

Comment: Thanks, that's a really comprehensive list :) The only other option which comes spontaneously to mind is to use Wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org) to capture the TCP stream directly. However that's only feasible for not too big videos and has to fail if the stream is encrypted (e.g. `rtmpe://`).

Answer (score 3):

Some great suggestions in the other post.  I can confirm that **RTMP Explorer** works great.

1. [Download the RTMP Explorer ZIP file](http://www.videohelp.com/download/rtmpexplorer.zip)
2. Extract the ZIP file and then run `rtmpExplorer.exe`
3. When the application window opens, put the URL of the webpage in the box and hit "Go"
   [image]
4. Right click the video player and select the resolution you want to download
   [image]
5. Hit play
6. Wait for the download to complete and reach 100%
   [image]
7. The video file has now been saved in the same folder as the EXE
   [image]

Comment: That... didn't work for flash videos.  Explorer just asks me to download flash and doesn't offer any right-click functionality.